# modal bootstrap angular 2 closes immediately

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular2-template

when I click to open the modal it closes
I tried this example [bootstrap modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal)
after searching I guess that the error is from loading NgbModal multipule times.. 
but I only added it on the module.ts and in this component

```
    import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      <button class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"> a</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>`

})


export class NgbdModalContent {
  @Input() name;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modalbs',
  templateUrl: './modalbs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modalbs.component.css']
})
export class ModalbsComponent  {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open() {
  console.log("open");
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  }
}
```

and in the module.ts :`import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ModalbsComponent, NgbdModalContent } from './modalbs/modalbs.component';`

Answer (score 2):

Create an css class which have opacity value  and set 1.
Add this css class to your modal options.
It is worked for me.

```
.modal-opened{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

import NgbModalOptions to your component and open modal with options

```
import { NgbModalOptions } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

open() {
    console.log("open");
    let options: NgbModalOptions = {windowClass: 'modal-opened'};
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent,options);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  }
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm not sure what happened, but perhaps at some point I introduced some CSS that broke my modal? Thanks!